# WPF + C# button to connect pages

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am trying to make a WPF program in VS express C# I have multiple pages/windows.

I have my main page with a nice picture and a button that says 'Start'.

I want this start button to connect to my contents page/window its called 'modules'.

For simplicity (haha) I am also using blend. I get the point of setting the on click event handler in blend then swapping over to VS. but what do I write in the gap to actually get the button to go to the module window/page. I have been reading up in my spare time and still cannot find a simple answer for an absolute beginner. I can find many samples on how to get a button to display " Hi WPF" or whatever using a text box but thats obvisously not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

i want to click the button and the start page/window to change to the 'module' window/page in the exact same way as blend sketch flow changes pages, in sketch flow you can just make the button navigate to the page you want. and that's all i want to do here   page1> to > page2 'module'